# Как изменить размер блока меню?

Tags: html, css

Приветствую.Меня интересует как сделать : 
http://cs310530.vk.me/v310530641/9e97/59gDwmTikIQ.jpg (НЕ реклама)
Из вот этого http://77.120.247.79/Test/ (НЕ реклама)
Примечание : Как изменить размер блока меню.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я вижу как минимум три меню на странице и ничего не вижу на скриншоте, потому что он микроскопических размеров. Опишите задачу подробнее.

Comment: Необходимо сократить размер блока где расположено меню.HOME и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav {
    background: #fafafa url(../img/nav-bg.png) repeat-x; // здесь и до следующего комментария - код, который уже существует
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #e3e1d9;
    height: 39px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 1000px; // фиксированная ширина, как и у контейнера ниже
    margin: 0 auto; // выравниваем по центру
    padding: 0 15px; // добавляем поля, поля плюс ширина - искомые 1030пкс
}
#search {
    float: right;
    margin: 7px 25px 0 0; // меняем внешний отступ, я так и не понял, почему он поехал, видимо из-за position:relative родителя
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!